# ipdb Step loop doesn't complete

Tags: python, django, ipdb

I am debugging a Django request, working with [ipdb step by step](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Continuing-and-Stepping.html) through to find the source of the problem. At a certain point, the stepping process, using `s` for `step` seems to loop endlessly. If I press `c` for `continue`, the program does not get caught at the same point, but continues to an error elsewhere (as expected). As well as being behaviour I did not expect, it also means I cannot find the source of the problem. Here is my console log which loops endlessly:

```
ipdb> s
False
> /Users/technical/.virtualenvs/wagtest-QzaRrIlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py(236)<genexpr>()
    235         self.check_apps_ready()
--> 236         return any(ac.name == app_name for ac in self.app_configs.values())
    237

ipdb> s
--Return--
False
> /Users/technical/.virtualenvs/wagtest-QzaRrIlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py(236)<genexpr>()
    235         self.check_apps_ready()
--> 236         return any(ac.name == app_name for ac in self.app_configs.values())
    237

ipdb> s
--Call--
False
> /Users/technical/.virtualenvs/wagtest-QzaRrIlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py(236)<genexpr>()
    235         self.check_apps_ready()
--> 236         return any(ac.name == app_name for ac in self.app_configs.values())
    237

ipdb> s
False
> /Users/technical/.virtualenvs/wagtest-QzaRrIlX/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py(236)<genexpr>()
    235         self.check_apps_ready()
--> 236         return any(ac.name == app_name for ac in self.app_configs.values())
    237

ipdb> locals()
{'.0': <odict_iterator object at 0x10fc30308>, 'app_name': 'django.contrib.sites', 'ac': <WagtailImagesAppConfig: wagtailimages>, '__return__': False}
```

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: It's looping through all the values in self.app_configs; each iteration is a separate step.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I did try `next` and `until` having thought that might be the case, but it didn't work. How else can I move through such iterations?

Comment: I usually put a breakpoint on the next line, eg `b 238`, and then `c` to continue until then.

Comment: If I manually put a break after line 236 as so: `self.check_apps_ready()
        return any(ac.name == app_name for ac in self.app_configs.values())
        import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()` then it just continues past it, possibly because the `return` means anything below, including the ipdb call, it gets skipped. Right?